# WebStorm shows an error when configuring Stylelint

Tags: sass, webstorm, stylelint

I ask for help in configuring Stylelint in the WebStorm IDE.

I have ESLint and Prettier configured. Everything works fine. I decided to add Stylelint (scss), but I don't understand what else I have to do?

[image]

**.stylelintrc.json:**

```json
{
    "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss", "stylelint-config-prettier-scss"]
}
```

**package.json:**

[image]

**WebStorm settings:**

[image]

Comment: It seems that the webstorm intelij integration does not work. It seems in the latest update it is ouputting the json format as is the default of the node API output. The only way I could fix it was downgrade to 15.11.0 and then downgrade the related plugins for v15 support

Comment: The same problem for me 
Did you find a solution to fix it?